# Backtracking in Python

Tags: python, backtracking

I have just started learning Python and tried to write down the backtracking algorithm, but it seems that I am doing something wrong.
Since I am new to this language, I have been trying to look it up on the internet, but did not understand very much of it.Here is my code:

```
n = 3
x = [0] * 3
k = 0
def init ():
    x[k] = 0
def succesor():
    if x[k] < n:
        x[k]+=1
        return 1
    return 0
def valid ():
    i = 1
    for i in range (0,k-1):
        if x[i] == x[k]:
            return 0
    return 1
def solutie ():
    return k == n
def afis():
    print(x)
def back ():
    k = 1
    avemsuccesor = 1
    init()
    while k > 0:
        while avemsuccesor and not valid():
            avemsuccesor = succesor()
        if avemsuccesor:
            if solutie:
                afis()
            else:
                k+=1
                init()
        else:
            k-=1
def main ():
    back()
main ()
```

When I run it, I only get a vector full of 0's.
Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 2):

One key problem is that:

```
if solutie:
```

is testing the truthiness of the *function*, which will always be `True`:

```
>>> bool(solutie)
True
```

rather than the truthiness of the value it returns; you should have:

```
if solutie():
        # ^ note parentheses
```

Also, none of your functions have arguments, so you rely entirely on variable scope for access. This is unwise, and makes the code very difficult to debug - you can't test any function in isolation. As a trivial example, compare:

```
def solutie():
    return k == n
```

with

```
def solutie(k, n):
    return k == n
```

With the former, testing is very difficult - what are `k` and `n`? Where do they come from? With the latter, it's a simple matter of

```
assert solutie(1, 1)
assert not solutie(1, 2)
```

The main problem you have stems from this: *because `k` is immutable, you always use the same value* in every function other than `back`. Although you assign `k += 1` in `back`, the other functions (e.g. `valid`) are still using `k == 0` from the outer scope. If you change every function to use explicit arguments and return values, e.g.:

```
 def successor(x, k, n):
     ...
     return True # use booleans rather than 0 or 1

 ...
     avemsuccesor = succesor(x, k, n)
```

You will quickly find that `k` goes out of range, causing an `IndexError`. I won't rewrite everything here - I will leave refactoring your code to pass values around explicitly and solving the errors that then crop up as an exercise for you.

Comment: So, for instance, shall I modify 
`k+=1
init(x,k)`

with 

`init(x,k+1)` ?

Comment: @epanicafrate no, you want to increment `k` in `back` as you do now (`k += 1`) but then pass *that value of `k`* to `init` (change `def init()` to `def init(x, k)` and change the call to `init(x, k)`).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that k is defined twice, once as 0 and once as 1. Inside valid, it chooses the global k = 0 but regardless, even k-1 is zero initially so valid() will return 1 on the first iteration. I don't understand the intention of this program but that is the reason it never gets to run successor() which actually modifies the vector's elements from zeros.

Comment: Although your suggestion to explicitly use argument and return values is a good one, lists (like `x`) are mutable, so changes made in the function *will* change the "global" `x`.

Comment: Ok, so here is a simplified version of the algorithm:
    `n = 3
x = [0] * 3
k = 0
def valid ():
    i = 1
    for i in range(0,k-1):
        if x[i] == x[k]:
            return 0
        return 1
def main ():
    k = 1
    x[k] = 0
    while k > 0:
        while x[k] < n and not valid():
                x[k]+=1;
        if x[k] < n:
            if k == n:
                print(x)
            else:
                k+=1
                x[k] = 0;
        else:
            k-=1

main ()`

What should I do in order to make it work?

Comment: What is the intention of this algorithm? (Using words)

Comment: @epanicafrate code is more-or-less unreadable in comments, particularly in Python where whitespace is important. **Edit the question** to explain the code you're running, what it's supposed to be doing and exactly what is wrong with it (error traceback, outputs, etc.).